# How to transform coordinates from WPF Image control to its Source and back?

Tags: c#, winforms, wpf-controls

How to accomplish this simple functionality (simple in Winforms) in WPF?
Image is displayed with Stretch = "Uniform". After clicking on the image the coordinates (with respect to the source image) are saved and the clicking point is shown (small rectangle) over the image.

In winforms I did it by finding zoom and offsets of the sourceimage within PictureBox and than easily converted the image coordinates. 
Next thing is in winforms I used GetGraphics() function so the marks were not persistent and could have been redrawn from the saved ones on every resize, the rectangles added in WPF stay ot their locations.

What is the best way to do this? Or is it better to use a WinForm control within the WPF window?

Edit: 
Scale computing - copied from Winforms and updated

```
    private void ComputeScale ()
    {
        if (image1.Source == null)
        {
            this.imageScale = 1;
            this.offsetX = 0;
            this.offsetY = 0;
            return;
        }

        //todo: picture has to be bigger than PictureBox
        decimal imW = (decimal)image1.Source.Width;
        decimal imH = (decimal)image1.Source.Height;
        decimal pbW = (decimal)image1.ActualWidth;
        decimal pbH = (decimal)image1.ActualHeight;
        decimal scaleX = pbW / imW;
        decimal scaleY = pbH / imH;
        decimal scale = Math.Min (scaleX, scaleY);
        decimal offsetX = Math.Round ((pbW - Math.Round (imW * scale)) / 2);
        decimal offsetY = Math.Round ((pbH - Math.Round (imH * scale)) / 2);

        this.imageScale = scale;
        this.offsetX = (int)offsetX;
        this.offsetY = (int)offsetY;
    }
```

Painting Rectangles

```
            Point p = e.GetPosition(image1);
            decimal x = ((decimal)(p.X - offsetX)) / imageScale;
            decimal y = ((decimal)(p.Y - offsetY)) / imageScale;

            System.Drawing.Point ClickedSample = new System.Drawing.Point((int)Math.Round(x), (int)Math.Round(y));

            Samples.Add(ClickedSample);
            //PaintSampleMark
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle();

            r.StrokeThickness=1;
            r.Stroke= Brushes.Blue;
            r.Width = sampleRadius*2;
            r.Height= sampleRadius*2;

            r.Margin = new Thickness ((double)(offsetX - sampleRadius + x), (double)(offsetY - sampleRadius + y), 0, 0);
            canvas1.Children.Add(r);
```

Comment: If you already have some WPF code for drawing the rectangle it may help to show some of that